# How can get location is on or off status after redirecting to location setting

Tags: android, android-intent, location

if location is off iam redirecting the user to location setting, how can i know that user have on the setting of not. Iam using the below code

```
startActivity(newIntent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startActivityForResult` ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)) to know when the user backs from the settings activity and returns to your application.

And in the callback method (`onActivityResult()`) you can check again to see if location services is ON or OFF.